# Как собрать 32 битную библиотеку на 64 битной платформе используя cmake?

Tags: cmake

Надо собрать библиотеку под 32 битное приложение. Как это сделать используя cmake?

Comment: Используя 32-х битный компилятор.

Comment: Так он у меня есть

Comment: Тогда используйте его. CMake это генератор скриптов, разрядность результата зависит от выбранного компилятора.

Comment: просто укажите какой компилятор нужно использовать в `CMAKE_******_COMPILER` и все